# emplace_back calls move constructor, and destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, stdvector

I try to emplace two instance of the class cBar to a vector with emplace_back function.

According to the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) calling an emplace_back only reserve the place in the vector, then create the new instance "in place".

Now, I tried to experiment with it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>


class cBar
{
public:

    cBar(const int index);
    cBar(cBar&& other); //needed for emplace_back?
    ~cBar();

private:
    cBar(const cBar& other) = delete;
    cBar& operator=(const cBar& other) = delete;

public:
    int                         mIndex;

};




cBar::cBar(const int index) : mIndex(index)
{
    std::cout << "cBar being created ..." << std::endl;
}
cBar::cBar(cBar&& other) : mIndex(other.mIndex)
{
    std::cout << "cBar being moved ..." << std::endl;
}
cBar::~cBar()
{
    std::cout << "cBar being destroyed ..." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<cBar> mBars;

    std::cout << "Begin to create 2 cBar instance, I am expecting 2 \"cBar being created ...\" messages here" << std::endl;
    mBars.emplace_back(0);//this supposed to call only cBar(const int index) constructor, and nothing more
    mBars.emplace_back(1);//this works as expected, only one constructor call

    //destroy all
    std::cout << "Destroy the 2 isntances (this works, I see the two expected \"cBar being destroyed ...\" messages here" << std::endl;
    mBars.clear();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Begin to create 2 cBar instance, I am expecting 2 "cBar being created ..." messages here
cBar being created ...
cBar being moved ...
cBar being destroyed ...
cBar being created ...
Destroy the 2 isntances (this works, I see the two expected "cBar being destroyed ..." messages here
cBar being destroyed ...
cBar being destroyed ...
```

If you run the one above, you will see that the first emplace_back creates the instance "in place", but then immediately call the move constructor, and then destructor is called.

What is more strange, that in case of the second emplace, I see the expected behavior: Only one constructor call.

I have two questions:

1. Why do I need to define a move constructor in my class if I just want to emplace_back items, and never use push_back.
2. In case of the first instance creation, why the move constructor, then the destructor is called? If I access the data of the first instance all seems to correct, so I have no idea why the move constructor, and destructor is called.

I use Visual Studio 2015.

Output with vector sizes in each step:

```
Begin to create 2 cBar instance, I am expecting 2 "cBar being created ..." messages here
Vector size:0
cBar being created ...
Vector size:1
cBar being moved ...
cBar being destroyed ...
cBar being created ...
Vector size:2
Destroy the 2 isntances (this works, I see the two expected "cBar being destroyed ..." messages here
cBar being destroyed ...
cBar being destroyed ...
```

Comment: Add `mBars.reserve(9);` before your tests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 2.In case of the first instance creation, why the move constructor, then the destructor is called?

Because the insertion of the 2nd element by [emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) causes the reallocation; the inner storage of the `vector` needs to be extended, the elements in the old storage have to be copied/moved to the new storage, then destroyed.

You can use [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) in advance to avoid reallocation.

> 1.Why do I need to define a move constructor in my class if I just want to emplace_back items, and never use push_back.

As the above explanation said, `vector` needs to move elements by copy/move operation. So you have to define the copy or move constructor for the class. This is true for both `emplace_back` and `push_back`, because they both add elements to `vector` and might cause reallocation.

Answer (score 3):

Odds are the capacity of your vector was one, and when you put the second element in, it had to resize the vector.  That can turn into a bunch of things being moved in memory, and the symptoms you see.

Kerreks advice is good.
I suggest printing the vectors capacity before and after each operation to see if the capacity change is the cause.

Comment: Wish I could flag two answers at once. Thanks for the help! Edited the question with the output.